# Sankey diagramm, multidimensional Array create with query in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, d3.js, multidimensional-array

im want create an multidimensional Array for d3.sankey.

But i dont get it how it works to build an multidimensional Array.

What i need is:

d3.Sankey needs an Input like:

```
{
"nodes":[
{"node":0,"name":"node0"},
{"node":1,"name":"node1"},
{"node":2,"name":"node2"},
{"node":3,"name":"node3"},
{"node":4,"name":"node4"}
],
"links":[
{"source":0,"target":2,"value":2},
{"source":1,"target":2,"value":2},
{"source":1,"target":3,"value":2},
{"source":0,"target":4,"value":2},
{"source":2,"target":3,"value":2},
{"source":2,"target":4,"value":2},
{"source":3,"target":4,"value":4}
]}
```

Acctually i build that thing with strings. Thats sound really complicated and it is. One mistake and it doesnt Work anymore.

So my question is how can i Build that form with arrays.

So first of all i call the Database to give me all the entries wich comes from and Inputtable.
Looks Like: (yes, im from Germany so some words in that query are german words ;) )

```
$stmt = self::$_db->prepare("SELECT BalancesheetInput.RessourceName, "
            . "SUM(BalancesheetInput.Amount) AS Amount, "
            . "Einheiten.Einheit AS Unit "
            . "FROM BalancesheetInput "
            . "INNER JOIN Einheiten ON Unit_FK = Unit_ID "
            . "GROUP BY BalancesheetInput.RessourceName");
        $stmt->execute();

        $fetcharray = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That "Input" query get the entries for the nodes and links wich should refer to one Node wich stands in the middle of the sankey-diagram (**for better understanding i added a Picture**)

Next step i need all the entries from an Outputtable

```
 $stmtOutput = self::$_db->prepare("SELECT BalancesheetOutput.RessourceName, "
            ."SUM(BalancesheetOutput.Amount) AS AmountOutput, "
            ."Einheiten.Einheit AS UnitOutput "
            ."FROM BalancesheetOutput "
            ."INNER JOIN Einheiten ON Unit_FK = Unit_ID "
            ."GROUP BY BalancesheetOutput.RessourceName");
        $stmtOutput->execute();
        $fetcharrayOutput = $stmtOutput->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

all these Entries refer from that Node in the Middle so its self (hope you understand what i mean)

What im doing atm is i get the Input and Output queries and put them together by creating a very long string.

```
$counter = 0;
    $ziel = count($fetcharray);
    $array_values = count($fetcharray);

    $counterafterInput = 0;

    $jsonNodes ='{"nodes":[';
    $jsonLinkes = '],"links":[';
    foreach ($fetcharray as $getnodes){

        if (($array_values-1) == $counter) {
           // saves node to string,
            //// wenn letzer Datenbankeintrag erreicht ist addet Schöneweide als Node
            $jsonNodes .= '{"node":'. $counter. ',"name":"' . $getnodes['RessourceName'] . '","units":"'.$getnodes['Unit'].'"},';
            $jsonNodes .= '{"node":'. ($counter+1). ',"name":"Schöneweide","units":"Blackbox"},';
           // $jsonNodes .= '{"node":'. ($counter+2). ',"name":"weiter","units":"'.$getnodes['Unit'].'"},'; //irgendwann obsolete

            // saves node to string, wenn letzer Datenbankeintrag erreicht ist
            $jsonLinkes .= '{"source":'.$counter .',"target":' .$ziel .  ',"value":' . $getnodes['Amount'] . ',"units":"'.$getnodes['Unit'].'"},';
           // $jsonLinkes .= '{"source":'.($counter+1) .',"target":' .($ziel+1) .  ',"value":' . $getnodes['Amount'] . ',"units":"'.$getnodes['Unit'].'"}';

            $counter++;
            $counterafterInput = $counter;
            $counter++;

        }
        else{
        //saves nodes to string while counter != Anzahl der Datenbankeinträge
        //If else weil durch Komma getrennte Schreibeweise die nodes und Links eingetragen werden .... geht in die if ,wenn der vorletzte eintrag erreicht wird um
        //die letze Node anzuhängen. Die letzte Node ist die Blackbox Schöneweide(oder später auch ein anderes Gebiet

            $jsonNodes .= '{"node":'. $counter. ',"name":"' . $getnodes['RessourceName'] . '","units":"'.$getnodes['Unit'].'"},';
            $jsonLinkes .= '{"source":'.$counter .',"target":' .$ziel .  ',"value":' . $getnodes['Amount'] . ',"units":"'.$getnodes['Unit'].'"},';


        $counter++;
    }
    }

    $counterOutput = 0;

    $array_values_output = count($fetcharrayOutput);
    $jsnonnodesOutput = "";
    $jsonLinkesOutput = "";


    foreach ($fetcharrayOutput as $getnodesOutput)
    {
        if (($array_values_output-1) == $counterOutput){

        $jsnonnodesOutput .= '{"node":'.$counter.',"name":"'.$getnodesOutput['RessourceName'].'","units":"'.$getnodesOutput['UnitOutput'].'"}';
        $jsonLinkesOutput .= '{"source":'.$counterafterInput.',"target":'.$counter.',"value":'.$getnodesOutput['AmountOutput'].',"units":"'.$getnodesOutput['UnitOutput'].'"}]}';
        }
        else
        {
            $jsnonnodesOutput .= '{"node":'.$counter.',"name":"'.$getnodesOutput['RessourceName'].'","units":"'.$getnodesOutput['UnitOutput'].'"},';
            $jsonLinkesOutput .= '{"source":'.$counterafterInput.',"target":'.$counter.',"value":'.$getnodesOutput['AmountOutput'].',"units":"'.$getnodesOutput['UnitOutput'].'"},';
            $counterOutput++;
            $counter++;
        }


    }

    $JSONstring = $jsonNodes. $jsnonnodesOutput . $jsonLinkes .$jsonLinkesOutput;


   return $JSONstring;
```

So let me explain what im doing:

First step i set a Counter.
Next i count all the entries in Query to set the Node in the middle.
For example i got 5 entries so i need to set the node in the middle to 6.
Nextstep is initialize

```
`$jsonNodes ='{"nodes":[';`
```

next step i run the foreach-loop to fill all the entries in string i need to get something like that

```
{"node":0,"name":"node0"},
```

my Code for that is

```
 $jsonNodes .= '{"node":'. $counter. ',"name":"' . $getnodes['RessourceName'] . '","units":"'.$getnodes['Unit'].'"},';
```

the Counter counts an Id for each entrie

and also i have to set Links. So the nodes refer to the Node in the middle

```
 $jsonLinkes .= '{"source":'.$counter .',"target":' .$ziel .  ',"value":' . $getnodes['Amount'] . ',"units":"'.$getnodes['Unit'].'"},';
```

So source is the same ID like in nodes, target is the node in the middle amount and units are self explanatory.

In short i do the same to get the Output just that the source is the node in the middle and the target is each node it selfs

Actually it works but i think there is a much more better solution with arrays.

so Now i need Help to create an Array which i can save as variable for Javascript.

If someone know how that works and tell me. That would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution with arrays is to build an array with the structure you want and then run it through [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$nodes = array();
$nodes[] = array('node' => 0, 'name' => 'node0');
$nodes[] = array('node' => 1, 'name' => 'node1');
$nodes[] = array('node' => 2, 'name' => 'node2');

$links = array();
$links[] = array('source' => 0, 'target' => 2, 'value' => 2);
$links[] = array('source' => 0, 'target' => 1, 'value' => 2);

echo json_encode(array('nodes' => $nodes, 'links' => $links));
// {"nodes":[{"node":0,"name":"node0"},{"node":1,"name":"node1"},{"node":2,"name":"node2"}],"links":[{"source":0,"target":2,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":1,"value":2}]}
```

Comment: wow, Thank you. Looks quite the same like my string. But it doesnt work. Dont know why. Errormeassage is "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined". When i switch back to my String-version everything works like expected. I have already compared both variables and it is exactly the same

Comment: Alright i check everthing twich in the console and something goes wrong with the data......  on my old version i got nodes =23 and Links = 21 and in the new version are just nodes = 22 and Links = 22. I will give a replay when i fixed the problem in my code ;)

Comment: Now it is working. Thanks alot for your help. Best thing on your method it is reallys clear and i could kill some errors that i never notice before :D